# Tauberian measures on a locally compact abelian group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Given a locally compact abelian group $G$ with Haar measure $m$, it is well-known that there exist measures $\mu\in M(G)$ which are singular (with respect to $m$), but the convolution product $\mu\ast\mu$ is absolutely continuous.

(Q.1) Is there any condition characterizing the measures $\mu$ which satisfy the following (opposite) $tauberian$ property: given $\nu \in M(G)$,  $\mu\ast\nu$ absolutely continuous implies $\nu$ absolutely continuous?

If $\mu_1$ is invertible in $M(G)$ and $\mu_2$ is absolutely continuous, then $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$ satisfies this tauberian property.

(Q.2) Are there further examples?

Comment: What is the definition of invertible measure? and what do you mean by $\mu_{2}$ to be a.c? wrt to $m$?

Comment: $(M(G),*)$ is a commutative Banach algebra. $\mu$ invertible means that there is $\nu$ such that $\mu * \nu =\delta_e$, where $e$ is the unit of $G$ ($\delta_e$ is the unit of $M(G)$), and $\mu_2$ a.c. wrt m means $A$ Borel subset of $G$ and $m(A) =0$ implies $\mu_1(A)=0$; equiv., there is $f_1 \in L_1(m)$ such that $d\mu_1 = f_1\cdot d m$.

Comment: Every $\mu\in M(G)$ can be decomposed as $\mu= \mu_d + \mu_c$ where $\mu_d$ is the discrete (atomic) part and $\mu_c$ is the continuous part (no atoms).\newline

Comment: CONTINUATION: It was proved by R. Doss [Studia Math. 45 (973), 111-117] that for every continuous measure $\mu$ there exists a non absolutely continuous measure $\mu$ such that $\mu *\nu$ is absolutely continuous. Therefore a measure satisfying the tauberian property has non-zero atomic part.

Comment: @M. Gonzalez, the Lebesgue decomposition statement you've written is false, as $\mu$ can be decomposed as a.c. part plus a singular part, but the singular need not be atomic. It can be for example a Cantor measure, or any measure of dimension less than $m$, but need not be discrete.

Comment: @Asaf, the decomposition I considered is $\mu=\mu_d +\mu_c$, discrete part plus continuous part. Then the continuous (no atoms) part can be decomposed in absolutely continuous plus singular continuous.

Comment: @M. Gonzalez, usually the decomposition is written as $\mu=\mu_{a.c}+\mu_{sing}+\mu_{d}$, as (for example) the Cantor measure is not atomic, but not a.c. wrt to Lebesgue. Anyways, as the Tauberian theorem usual proof involves analysing a suitable summation kernel via harmonic analysis, it seems profitable to try to attack the problem you're facing via Fourier transform on $L^1(G)$ (I think that maybe Kauffman did work in those lines). Detecting atoms in measure via its Fourier transform can be done via the so-called Wiener's lemma.